# Flask route giving 404 with floating point numbers in the URL

Tags: python, routes, flask, http-status-code-404, werkzeug

I have the following route definition in my Flask app's server.py:

```
@app.route('/nearby/<float:lat>/<float:long>')
def nearby(lat, long):
    for truck in db.trucks.find({'loc': {'$near': [lat, long]}}).limit(5):
        if truck.has_key('loc'):
            del truck['loc']
    return json.dumps(trucks)
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:5000/nearby/37.7909470419234/-122.398633589404`, I get a 404.

The other routes work fine, so it's an issue with this one. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do simpler numbers work? `/nearby/42/42`?

Comment: Have you tried only positive float values ? I recall reading on werkzeug routing that for floats, negative is not allowed. http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/

Comment: @codegeek is right. Negative numbers are not supported. As stated here: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.FloatConverter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the built in FloatConverter can only handle positive numbers, I pass the coordinates as strings, and use Python's float() method to convert them to floats.

Answer (score 25):

The built-in [`FloatConverter`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/routing/#werkzeug.routing.FloatConverter) has a `signed` argument that can enable matching signed values.

```py
@app.route("/nearby/<float(signed=True):lat>/<float(signed=True):long>
```

---

Prior to Werkzeug 0.15, the built-in converter did not handle negative numbers. Write a custom converter to handle negatives. This converter also treats integers as floats, which also would have failed. The built-in doesn't handle integers because then `/1` and `/1.0` would point to the same resource, but for the positions you're trying to match that probably doesn't matter.

```
from werkzeug.routing import FloatConverter as BaseFloatConverter

class FloatConverter(BaseFloatConverter):
    regex = r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?'

# before routes are registered
app.url_map.converters['float'] = FloatConverter
```

Answer (score 8):

As of Werkzeug 0.15 the [built-in float converter](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/routing/#werkzeug.routing.FloatConverter) has a `signed=True` parameter, which you can use for this:

```
@app.route('/nearby/<float(signed=True):lat>/<float(signed=True):long>')
```