# Flask url pattern matching for int not matching negative integers

Tags: python, flask

Suppose I have an endpoint where I use an integer param to determine the direction of an operation:

```
@app.route('/post/<int:direction>')
def move(direction):
    if direction == 1:
        print "Moving right"
    elif direction == -1: 
        print "Moving left"
    else:
        print "Not moving anywhere"
```

But somehow when passed in `-1` it will cause `error 404`, does the pattern matching only work for positive integers?

Comment: Check [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639363/flask-route-giving-404-with-floating-point-numbers-in-the-url)

Comment: [Here is the link](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/routing.py#L1048) to the Werkzeug router definition for ints. You can test that regex pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/Iizje1/1) (note it says no match). You can write a custom router or simply omit the `int:` and convert it yourself.